# Sums of squares via semidefinite programming for the complex free group algebra

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, sums-of-squares, noncommutative-rings

In the algebra of real noncommutative polynomials (the “free monoid algebra” over the real field) it is possible to reduce the question of whether an element is a sum of hermitian squares and commutators to [a semidefinite programming problem](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~igorklep/ncsostools_manual30may010.pdf). This arises in the study of *free semialgebraic geometry* stemming from Helton’s fundamental result that “positive” noncommutative polynomials are sums of squares.

[Theorem 6.1 of Netzer and Thom (attributed to Schmüdgen)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.5619.pdf) yields that the analogue of Helton’s theorem holds for the complex group algebra of a nonabelian free group.

> **Question:** Can the the question of whether an element the complex group algebra of a noncommutative free group is a sum of hermitian squares and commutators be reduced to a semidefinite programming
>   problem?

Any reference for this sort of reduction, or any comment on the difficulties of obtaining such an approach, is welcome. One motivation for this question is that in the proof of Theorem 2.1 of [this paper](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~igorklep/ncsostools_manual30may010.pdf) the absence of polynomial identities cited seems to hold over any commutative ground ring, suggesting that an algorithmic approach might be possible over the complex group algebra. A second motivation is given by J[uschenko and Popovych's reduction of the Connes Embedding Problem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.2163), which requires dealing with the complex free group algebra. Of course, my favorite answer would point to some code that could check whether a given element of the complex free group algebra could be written as a sum of squares plus commutators!

**EDIT:** It seems that testing whether an element is a sum of squares in the real group algebra [does reduce to a semidefinite programming problem](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2488.pdf). Is there a difficulty in passing to the complex case (are there no semidefinite programming algorithms for working over the complex field)?

Comment: Copy ü from my comment :-) (I can't edit less than 6 char-s)

Comment: On MacOS: Use Option+u to get the accent, then type u to place accent on it.

Comment: On Windows: `alt gr`+`y`

Comment: Actually on MacOS, you can simply hold the 'u' key, and you will be prompted for a bunch of different accents.

Comment: @TonyHuynh (sorry for the comment noise): Some users like to disable that "bug / feature" on inputting by holding down, because it comes in the way of fast typing :-) But yes, that is an option for the default usage on a Mac, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @everyone: Thank you for the many umlaut suggestions. I should have been more clear about the genesis of my comment: I was in a hurry and really wanted the TeX to compile…and was surprised that it wouldn't!