# Sums of hermitian squares in free abelian group algebras and real positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, real-algebraic-geometry, sums-of-squares, positivity

A little context for the following question, first. As Noah Stein notes in a comment below, the present question is closely related to the free semialgebraic geometry studied by Helton and his colleagues. In fact, working on the free nonabelian monoid rather than the free abelian group as I do below, something very close to an affirmative answer to the present question holds (see [Proposition 2.1 here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~igorklep/ncsostools_manual30may010.pdf)), but the proof of this strongly uses the fact that in a free monoid there can be no "multiplicative cancellation of terms". Roughly, the present question asks what happens if we allow multiplicative inverses of elements. A related question of mine is [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219473/sums-of-squares-via-semidefinite-programming-for-the-complex-free-group-algebra)

Suppose $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a symmetric matrix, and let $G$ be the free abelian group on $n$ generators $a_{1},...,a_{n}$. Let $\mathbb{R}G$ be the real group algebra of $G$ with involution $(\sum \lambda_{g}g)^{*}=\sum \lambda_{g}g^{-1}$. Suppose that the quadratic *-polynomial $\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}A_{ij}a_{i}^{*}a_{j}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}h_{k}^{*}h_{k}$ for some $h_{1},...,h_{N}\in \mathbb{R}G$, i.e. is a sum of hermitian squares in the group algebra. Does this imply $A=B^{T}B+D$ for some $B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $D\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ a diagonal matrix with zero trace?

Comment: The setup reminds me a bit of Bill Helton's work (with various coauthors) on polynomials in non-commuting variables and the positivity and convexity thereof.  However, in that work it is the algebra on the free monoid that is involved (there are no inverses) and the involution is reversal of order of the strings.  So I'm not sure if any of the techniques there would be useful, but I'm leaving this comment just in case.

Comment: Thanks, Noah! This is *precisely* what I want to know: What happens when we add these inverses?

Comment: This feels like it should have something to do with classical Fourier analysis and positive-definite functions... (which, I believe, is part of what Helton and al are trying to generalize)

Comment: @Yemon: My calculations suggest you may be right about this. Can you think of any good references that may discuss this sort of thing?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind right now, John, but I'll have a think about this later

Comment: @Yemon Choi: What is annoying is that if we are working over the complex scalars this is painfully close to true. If the quadratic polynomial in question is a sum of squares then substituting unit modulus complex numbers in for the u_i and u_j will always yield a positive number. If only this were true for arbitrary complex numbers, we'd have A is PSD. Can you see how to fix this argument?

Comment: @JonBannon This is exactly what I was thinking - each point in the n-torus defines a homomorphism from G to the n-torus, and you apply it to both sides, to get $\langle A\xi,\xi\rangle \geq 0$ for all $\xi \in {\mathbb T}^n$. But as you say, it's not clear how to get from this to having the same inequality for all $\xi\in {\mathbb C}^n$...

Comment: @YemonChoi: Embarrassing blind spot at the top, but the modified question may actually be the modification needed, if you'd like to have a look: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/238952/a-characterization-or-not-of-positive-semidefinite-matrices

Comment: @JonBannon I've consulted my brain; it told me to look sad and say "D'oh". (D'oh.)